# Numpy : cumulative difference in a list

Tags: python, numpy, loops

I'm stuck on a iteration problem.
I have a list of numbers, like: list = [100, 70, 25, 10, 5].
I would like to iterate over the list and generate a new array, such that each "result" becomes the new number from which the next is subtracted:

100-70 = 30

30 (result) - 25 = 5

5 (result) - 10 = -5

-5 (result) - 5 = -10

(I think you get the idea)

new_array = [30, 5, -5, -10]

I am not able to arrive at the solution with Numpy.
Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Why do you subtract 10 twice?

Comment: that is probably just a typo... let me fix the question

Comment: Both work; I'm accepting the second one only because it is more "Pythonic".  Thank you both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the subtract ufunc with [numpy.ufunc.accumulate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html).

```
numbers = [100, 70, 25, 10, 5]
result = np.subtract.accumulate(numbers)[1:]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[ 30   5  -5 -10]
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone's looking to do this *without* numpy:

```
from itertools import accumulate
import operator
data = [100, 70, 25, 10, 5]
result = list(accumulate(data, operator.sub))[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
main = [100,70,25,10,5]
new_main = []  #modified this line
current_difference = main[0]
for element in main[1:]:
    new_main.append(current_difference - element)
    current_difference-=element

new_main.append(current_difference - main[-1])
print(new_main)
```

Comment: Did you mean `new_main = []` instead of `new_arr = []`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the typo!